# Rails 4 multiple polymorphic has_one relations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to get three polymorphic associations working from my `Booth` model with below

```
has_one :uploaded_file, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploaded_file

has_one :company_logo, as: :imageable, class_name: 'UploadedFile', dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_logo

has_one :booth_main_image, as: :imageable, class_name: 'UploadedFile', dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :booth_main_image
```

This however does not work and I'm getting same values in the view when I use `build` method on the resource for that association separately.

In my `uploaded_files` table in the database I have `imageable_id` and `imageable_type`
I want to reuse this for things like company logo and booth main image because otherwise I have to create more columns to support other polymorphic associations and they will be left with `null` if not used.

Below is my model for `UploadedFile`:

```
class UploadedFile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    has_attached_file :assets

    validates_attachment_content_type :assets, 
        :content_type => /^image\/(png|gif|jpeg)/,
        :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
        :message => "only (png|gif|jpeg) images are allowed and the size cannot exceed 5mb",
        :size => { :in => 0..5000.kilobytes }

end
```

Is there a way to utilise one set of polymorphic columns for all of the above associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are having this problem is because `has_one` will ensure that only one record in the target table (`uploaded_files` in your case), will point back to the Booth model.  If you want to differentiate between different types of the same model, you'll need to set a flag somewhere that indicates which type it is.

To do this, first you'll need to add a column that identifies the image type:

```
# in a migration
def change
  add_column :uploaded_files, :image_type, :string
end
```

You can define the expected image types as constants:

```
class UploadedFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  IMAGE_TYPE_STANDARD = 'Standard'
  IMAGE_TYPE_LOGO     = 'Logo'
  IMAGE_TYPE_BOOTH    = 'Booth'
end
```

Now your associations should reflect these types:

```
class Booth < ActiveRecord::Base
  # optional - if you want to access all attached uploads
  has_many :uploaded_files, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy

  has_one  :uploaded_file, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy, 
           conditions: { image_type: UploadedFile::IMAGE_TYPE_STANDARD }
  has_one  :company_logo, :as => :imageable, :class_name => 'UploadedFile', 
           :dependent => :destroy, 
           conditions: { image_type: UploadedFile::IMAGE_TYPE_LOGO }
  has_one  :booth_main_image, :as => :imageable, :class_name => 'UploadedFile', 
           :dependent => :destroy, 
           conditions: { image_type: UploadedFile::IMAGE_TYPE_BOOTH }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for ...
end
```

Note that you won't have to set the `image_type` manually.  Since the type is set by the condition, ActiveRecord will set it for you when you build or create off one of the `has_one` associations:

```
upload = @booth.build_uploaded_file(asset: some_asset)
upload.image_type 
=> 'Standard'
```

Comment: In my opinion, the type CONSTANTS in the `UploadedFile` class are an indication that more classes are needed. Why not make separate models for `UploadedFile`, `CompanyLogo`, and `BoothMainImage`? I think that would be much easier to reason about.

Comment: In later versions of Rails 4, the conditions key has been removed. How should we do this now?

Comment: @EtiennevanDelden `conditions` is replaced by `where`: `has_one  :uploaded_file, -> { where image_type: UploadedFile::IMAGE_TYPE_STANDARD }, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy`